# difference between master and transaction table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Why do we need to have two tables (master and transaction table) of any topic like `sales`,`purchase`,etc.. What should be the relationship between the two tables and what should be the difference between them. Why do we really need them.

Comment: Consider asking on http://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: usually a master table would contain information at a high level.. who it is being sold to, customer id, etc. transaction table would be what you're selling, item number, qty etc.  as far as why.. well, there would be no point in saying, selling part a to Joe Bloggs of 111 SomeStreet, SomeTown.. part b to Joe Bloggs of 111 SomeStreet, Some Town.. part c.  etc. when you can just say, customer = Joe Bloggs, and then part a, qty = 1, part b, qty = 1 etc.   and finally, relationship might be order_id or similar

Comment: Because of [Database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). See example with customers and their TXs.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Master and Transaction tables are needed in the database schema specially in the verticals of sales.

**Master Data**: Data which seldom changes.
For example, if a company has a list of 5 customer then they
will maintain a customer master table having the name and
address of the customers alongwith other data which will
remain permanent and is less likely to change.

**Transaction Data**: Data which frequently changes. For
example, the company is selling some materials to one of the
customer.So they will prepare a sales order for the
customer. When they will generate a sales order means they
are doing some sales transactions.Those transactional data
will be stored in Transactional table.

This is really required to maintain database normalization.

Comment: Here's a detailed comparison of the two. https://metamug.com/article/difference-between-master-and-transaction-table.html

Comment: Hi guys, a small clarification, I am trying to create the main table by joining Sales Data and Customer for my analysis and a continuous monitoring dashboard. So can I call my main table as Master Data or Master table?

Answer (score 3):

In the end, it really depends on the type of data you are working with. If you have a specific example, that might give us a better indication on what you are trying to do. However, in general, a master table would theoretically be constant in relationship to habitual changes seen in your transaction table.

Answer (score 3):

#### Master Table

Master data is for capturing the system. Designing master table is the first step of database design. Master tables hold basic information of the system. To understand master tables, you need to understand the concept of a transaction.

#### Transaction Table

A transaction is an activity performed by entities within the system. These activities are captured to represent events like item purchase, ticket booking. Understanding transactions will give you clearer distinction of master tables from transaction tables.

#### Example

For example, to describe a class of students all the information needed will be part of master tables like student info, class info, teacher info, subject info. But to know what daily attendance of the students will be captured in the transaction table.

#### Reference

Here is an article to help distinguish the two. https://metamug.com/article/difference-between-master-and-transaction-table.html